# Getting syntax error in code at remainder='passthrough' in below code snippet

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[3]), remainder='passthrough'])
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x), dtype = np.float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be as follows:

```
import ColumnTransformer 

ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[3]), 
                        ],remainder='passthrough') 

x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x), dtype = np.float)
```